# Query to return just unique value from last column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I have a query that returns everything as wanted. But I do not want duplicates. Already tried "group by" but I get the exact same result.

```
select distinct eq.id as id, tipo.descripcion as tipoId, eq.tagId, eq.periodoId, eq.asignado, op.numOpcion as empleadoId
from Empleados emp inner join dbo.Opciones op ON op.empleadoId = emp.id 
inner join dbo.TipoEquipo tipo ON tipo.id = op.tipoEquipoId 
inner join dbo.Equipos eq ON eq.tipoId = tipo.id
where emp.Id = 1 
order by op.numOpcion
```

I get this.

```
id  tipoId  tagId   periodoId   asignado    empleadoId
1   Macbook tag1           1    Si             1
3   iMac    tag3           1    Si             2
5   Dell Lap OP tag5       1    No             3
6   Dell Lap OP tag6       1    No             3
```

Trying to get unique (the first value for empleadoId). Like this.

```
id  tipoId  tagId   periodoId   asignado    empleadoId
1   Macbook tag1           1    Si             1
3   iMac    tag3           1    Si             2
5   Dell Lap OP tag5       1    No             3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get duplicate rows because you have a `eq.id` which has unique id so, you can remove it or use `row_number()` :

```
select top (1) with ties eq.id as id, tipo.descripcion as tipoId, eq.tagId, eq.periodoId, eq.asignado, op.numOpcion as empleadoId
from Empleados emp inner join 
     dbo.Opciones op 
     ON op.empleadoId = emp.id inner join 
     dbo.TipoEquipo tipo 
     ON tipo.id = op.tipoEquipoId inner join 
     dbo.Equipos eq 
     ON eq.tipoId = tipo.id
where emp.Id = 1 
order by row_number() over (partition by tipo.descripcion, eq.periodoId, eq.asignado, op.numOpcion order by eq.id desc);
```

Comment: This does work like a charm! Just one more thing, is there a way to order it by op.numOpcion? Tried order by to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two rows with `Dell` as you've used operator `distinct` for `eq.id`.
So you can:

```
select 
  tipo.descripcion as tipoId
, eq.tagId
, eq.periodoId
, eq.asignado
, op.numOpcion as empleadoId
from Empleados emp inner join dbo.Opciones op ON op.empleadoId = emp.id 
inner join dbo.TipoEquipo tipo ON tipo.id = op.tipoEquipoId 
inner join dbo.Equipos eq ON eq.tipoId = tipo.id
where emp.Id = 1
group by   tipo.descripcion
         , eq.tagId
         , eq.periodoId
         , eq.asignado
         , op.numOpcion 
order by op.numOpcion
```

Or just use subquery and then `GROUP BY` without `id`:

```
select q.tipoId, q.tagId, q.periodoId, q.asignado, q.empleadoId
from
(
select 
distinct eq.id as id
, tipo.descripcion as tipoId
, eq.tagId
, eq.periodoId, 
eq.asignado, op.numOpcion as empleadoId
from Empleados emp inner join dbo.Opciones op ON op.empleadoId = emp.id 
inner join dbo.TipoEquipo tipo ON tipo.id = op.tipoEquipoId 
inner join dbo.Equipos eq ON eq.tipoId = tipo.id
where emp.Id = 1 
)q
group by q.tipoId, q.tagId, q.periodoId, q.asignado, q.empleadoId
order by q.empleadoId
```